# How to remove plurals in Lucene.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net, stemming, lemmatization

I'm trying to extract some keywords from a text. It works quite fine but I need to remove plurals.

As I'm already using Lucene for searching purpose, I'm trying to use it to extract keyword from indexed terms.

1st, I index the document in a RAMDirectory index,

```
RAMDirectory idx = new RAMDirectory();
using (IndexWriter writer = 
    new IndexWriter(
        idx,
        new CustomStandardAnalyzer(StopWords.Get(this.Language),
        Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, this.Language),
        IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED))
{
    writer.AddDocument(createDocument(this._text));
    writer.Optimize();
}
```

Then, I extract the keywords:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
using (var reader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true))
{
    var tv = reader.GetTermFreqVector(0, "text");
    if (tv != null)
    {
        string[] terms = tv.GetTerms();
        int[] freq = tv.GetTermFrequencies();

        for (int i = 0; i < terms.Length; i++)
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(freq[i], terms[i]));
    }
}
```

in the list of terms I can have terms like "president" and "presidents"
How could I remove it?
My CustomStandardAnalyzer use this:

```
public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
{
    //create the tokenizer
    TokenStream result = new StandardTokenizer(this.version, reader);

    //add in filters
    result = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Snowball.SnowballFilter(result, this.getStemmer()); 
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    result = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(result);
    result = new StopFilter(true, result, this.stopWords ?? StopWords.English);

    return result;
}
```

So I already use the SnowballFilter (with the correct language specific stemmer). 
How could I remove plurals?

Comment: It must be something in parts of the code that you are not showing, what you show us should work if you use a Porter Stemmer. I'll put some code thats basically yours with some stuff I hardcoded (stemmer) and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My output from the following program is:

```
text:and
text:presid
text:some
text:text
text:with
```

```
class Program
{
    private class CustomStandardAnalyzer : Analyzer
    {
        public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
        {
            //create the tokenizer
            TokenStream result = new StandardTokenizer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, reader);
            //add in filters
            result = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Snowball.SnowballFilter(result, new EnglishStemmer()); 
            result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
            result = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(result);
            result = new StopFilter(true, result, new HashSet<string>());
            return result;
        }
    }

    private static Document createDocument(string text)
    {
        Document d = new Document();
        Field f = new Field("text", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS);
        f.SetValue(text);
        d.Add(f);
        return d;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        RAMDirectory idx = new RAMDirectory();
        using (IndexWriter writer =
            new IndexWriter(
                idx,
                new CustomStandardAnalyzer(),
                IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED))
        {
            writer.AddDocument(createDocument("some text with president and presidents"));
            writer.Commit();
        }

        using (var reader = IndexReader.Open(idx, true))
        {
            var terms = reader.Terms(new Term("text", ""));
            if (terms.Term != null)
                do
                    Console.WriteLine(terms.Term);
                while (terms.Next());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is that I want to retrieve keywords, and "presid" is not a keyword, it should return "president". I tried with SnowballFilter but it stem the word, which is different from "just" removing plurals. The keyword must be existing words because it'll be visible by the user

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand. I dont know if anything like that has already be done in .NET, but Solr (java) has the solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory which is a stemmer that only process plural forms

Comment: I'll have a look to the code source of this class and check if I can convert it to c#. I also found another plurals remover code in c#. But both are only for english, and my package must support at least 3 language (en, fr, nl).